# Wrong number format when opening ASCII with labtalk origin9.1

Tags: ascii, number-formatting, openfiledialog, originlab

I have a problem reading ASCII-Files into Origin9.1. My ASCII-File looks like below: (note that I have 1 space before , 2 spaces between and 1 space after the numbers)

```
C:\amiX_TimeHist_P1.dat:

 0,19325E-02  0,10000E+00 
 0,97679E-11  0,99997E-11 
 0,19769E+10  0,10025E+00 
 0,39169E+00  0,11636E+00 
 0,47918E+00  0,13156E+00
```

later I want to do the following with a scr-File but for now I write the following in Origin2015 in the Script-LabTalk-window:

```
open -w C:\amiX_TimeHist_P1.dat;
```

That command works but the numbers I get are in a wrong format: 
[image]

When I read the file with the Import-wizzard or with ASCII-Import I can choose several options to fit the numbers correctly in the my columns. But this has to be done automatically.

Is there a way to read an ASCII-File uncluding setting parameters when using a script?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `open` you should use `impASC` to import ASCII data. Then you can specify some options to the command. In your case the following should work:

> impASC fname:=C:\amiX_TimeHist_P1.dat options.FileStruct.DataStruct:=2 options.FileStruct.MultipleDelimiters:=" " options.FileStruct.NumericSeparator:=1;

If you just type `impASC` in your script window, in the following dialog box you can edit the import options and display the corresponding skript command.